# Overflow attack to call function

Tags: stack, overflow, stack-overflow

I have an assignment from school (I will not ask any question that will give me the answer to the assignment)

We have been given the following code in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
char * stuff = 0;
int len = 0;

vulnerable();
return 0;
}

int vulnerable( void ) {
char buf[100];

printf("Please enter your hacker name: ");
fflush(stdout);
gets(buf);
printf("\"%s\"\n can hack this?" , buf );
}

void notcalled( void ) {
char *secret = "Iouf jmmb, cbsb sftufo lwbs!";
int i;

printf("The Secret string is: ");
for( i = 0 ; secret[i] ; i++ )
    if( secret[i] >= 'a' && secret[i] <= 'z' )
        printf("%c" , secret[i] -1 );
    else
        printf("%c" , secret[i] );
printf("\n");
}
```

I have compiled the program using the command:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o oflow oflow.c
```

I want to know if I am "right on track".

The first thing I did was to find the function "notcalled()" address, after that I have been looking at the stack while running gdb and trying to figure out where to put this address.

I have also been using following perl script to overflow the program:

```
perl -e 'print "A"x312 ."\xb0\x85\x04\x08"' | ./oflow
```

(note that the value 312 is just an example)

My question is: How can I find out where to place the address in the stack and how to calculate how many bytes I have to fill to overflow. (I don't want the answer, I want hints and tips to solve my problem)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an exact answer you would really need to provide the disassembly of the vulnerable method since it's going to vary depending upon the hardware you're running on.

A function call typically consists of something like this:

```
1 Push arguments on to the stack.
2 Call method.
3 Clean up the stack.
```

The call operation is essentially the combination of two instructions:

```
2.1 Push the address of line 3 onto the stack. 
2.2 Jump to the address of the method being called.
```

The method being called typically consists of something like this:

```
4 Create a stack frame for the method (something like below)
     push bp
     mov sp, bp
5 Create space for local variables on the stack
     sub 0x64, sp
6 Do stuff....
7 Clean up the stack frame.
     mov bp, sp
     pop bp
8 Return from the method.
     ret
```

**Figuring out where to put the address on the stack**

The `ret` instruction pops the address pushed when the method was called, into the instruction pointer.  The goal is to change this address so that instead of pointer pushed at line 3 it is pointing at your `notcalled` method.  So, you need to get the address onto the stack just past outside the methods stack frame.

**Figuring out how to trigger the overflow**

As you probably already know, the vulnerable part of the method call is it's call to `gets`.  This takes input from `stdin` and keeps collecting input until it gets to an end of line.  Since it doesn't take in a buffer size, this means that it is possible to pass more characters to `gets` than the buffer it is pointing at can hold hence you can trigger a buffer overflow.

**Figuring out how many bytes are needed to overflow**

As I've said above, you trigger the overflow by over filling the buffer.  So, the size of the input is going to be some function of (buffer size) + (possibly any other local variables) + (the stack frame).  You can either work this out by looking at the disassembly, or do it through a little bit of trial and error to see how you are filling the buffer and overflowing it through the stack.

Comment: Sorry for not saying thanks in time! Really helped me! Thank you so much and again, sorry for the late comment :)